# Where is my store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am migrating from ember-data 0.0.14 to ember-data 1.0.0-beta.6. I have been following [the guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/eeb6162f65513caa19ce18887c3f4d1c2014d80c/TRANSITION.md)

I am preloading some data needed by my application, triggering this pre-load when the application is ready. But I have lost the store!

```
/// application.js

var App = Ember.Application.createWithMixins({

    ...

    ready: function () {
        this.preLoadData();
    },

    ...
});

/// load_data.js

function preLoadData() {
    var store = this.Store;
    if (DEBUG) { console.log('preLoadData > this=%o store=%o', this, store); }
    store.find('node');  // was this.Node.find();
}
App.preLoadData = preLoadData;
```

But `this.Store` is not the store (I do not know what that is!). Also tried with `this.store`, but it is undefined, so I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined
```

I have even tried doing:

```
// inject the store into all components
SettingsApp.inject('component', 'store', 'store:main');
```

Whatever that magic means (what is `'component'`? Is it component `'component'`, or any *component*? What is a *component*?), but didn't help.

How can I access an instance of the store directly from my `App`?

*Edit*: I have found [component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html) in the documentation, but this is not what I need: I want to access the store from the `App`.

Comment: it should be `this.store`. What I believe the problem in this case is the scope of `this`. You might be calling `this` that is not a ember object.

Comment: `this` is my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access store from Application object which is not possible.  You could use something like this,

```
var store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main')
```

### To initialize your app

But I believe you want to initialize your app with some preloaded data. You could use initializer to do such work.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "preload data",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main');
    store.find('node');
  }
});
```